# How to store only one duplicate key in hashmap.

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

how will display data from table product_Details: p2,p5,s1 using hashMap and sql query and display all product_name also using hashMap only.

```
    table: Product_Details.

      product_id     product_name
       1001              p1 
       1001              p2
       1002              p3  
       1002              p4
       1002              p5
       1002              s1
```

Comment: i have to display product_name only 1001-p2,1002-p5,1002-s1 and also all product_name using hashMap

Comment: A [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) cannot contain duplicate keys, neither one nor more.

Comment: I think we understand what you want. We are asking : what did you try? Where are you stuck? What makes you think any Java map would work with duplicate keys? Or do you assume this is a site where people do your work for free?

Comment: First learn how to ask a question first. You didnt tell, what you want. Illogical question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a key using both column.

For example using delimiter as _ between the values or make a new Object as the key.

Second option is to check if value exists and to concat new value with a delimter.